# ListView not returning selected item after filtering to previous activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView populated by a String array. The user searches through edittext and it filters from the list, but when I click on one of the list items after filtering, the selected item is not returned but something else entirely. This was why it was going wrong:

Filter code:

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
```

List item click code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String s = array[position];
            intent.putExtra(s);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Then I would read the string through OnActivityResult. The problem is that when the list is filtered, the list items are reduced. On selecting one of the items returns the position number of the **reduced list**, not the array. That's why the returned string is actually the string according to the array not according to the reduced list. How can I overcome this ?

Comment: Can you, instead of keeping the array of string, keep a HashMap<Int, String> with int representing the id? Then based on the user click, see what item has the given id and find it in the original HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is simple when you filtered the list and click on item you won't get the filtered item clicked because in `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {...}` you are passing `position` of original list not the filtered list.

Workaround is instead of getting from main list try getting it like this :

```
String a = array[parent.getItemAtPosition(position)];
or
String a = array[adapter.getItem(position)];
or
String a = array[(String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)];
```